# How to search a list of integers for the integers that satisfy more than one criteria with loops?

Tags: python-3.6

I need to create a loop that can search through a list of integers for the integers that are divisble by 5 and 7 while allowing the reader to determine the starting and ending number of the list .Below is my code ,but for some reason it only prints the last number of the list that satisfies the condition and not everything?What is wrong with my code?I am only allowed to do this with loop functions .

```
startRange =int(input("Enter the starting number:"))
endRange = int(input("Enter the end number:"))
a=range(startRange,endRange)
b=list(a)
c=b.append(int(endRange))
#find numbers
def findNumbers(startRange,endRange):
for i in b:
    if i%5==0 and i%7==0:
        Numbers=[]
        z=i
        y=Numbers.append(i)
        continue
print(favNumbers)

return favNumbers
```

Comment: Could you fix the code? I submitted an edit but I'm not even sure I have what you mean. Once you fix the indentation we can see what is going wrong, though right off the bat you may want to show where you declare `favNumbers`. Is `favNumbers` an int? A list?

Comment: sorry I forgot to remove the fav

Comment: basically what I want to do is for the loop to search for all multiples of 5 and 7 within the range defined and at the end of the program ,I want the program to print out the numbers in a list.

Comment: THIS question is SOLVED

Comment: You can click "accept answer" on the answer that helped you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had a few problems, so I tried to iron them out here:

```
def findNumbers(list): #findNumbers is now passed a list
    favNumbers=[] #This needs to be initialized before the for loop, or it will be reset on every iteration
    for i in list:
        if i%5==0 and i%7==0:   
            favNumbers.append(i) #The number is appended to favNumbers, and you do not set this equal to a variable.
    return favNumbers


def main(): #I don't know about you, but my CS prof would kill me if I didn't have a main()...
    startRange = int(input("Enter the starting number:"))
    endRange = int(input("Enter the end number:"))
    mylist = list(range(startRange,endRange+1)) #This allows you to include endRange in the list without appending it yourself
    print(findNumbers(mylist))

main()
```

I tried commenting areas that I made significant changes, but if you have questions comment below!

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Alternatively, here's code without a `main()` ~~shudder~~ that is closer to what you originally had, with a findNumbers function that takes in two ints rather than a list!

```
startRange = int(input("Enter the starting number:"))
endRange = int(input("Enter the end number:"))

#find numbers
def findNumbers(startRange, endRange):
    a = range(startRange,endRange+1) #Again, this way you don't have to say c = b.append(int(endRange))
    b = list(a)
    favNumbers = [] #This needs to be initialized here, or else it won't return the list you want.
    for i in b:
        if i%5==0 and i%7==0:
            favNumbers.append(i)
    print(favNumbers)
    return favNumbers

findNumbers(startRange, endRange)
```

Comment: Nice,this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
startRange =int(input("Enter the starting number:"))
endRange = int(input("Enter the end number:"))
a= range(startRange,endRange)
b= list(a)
c= b.append(int(endRange))

#find numbers
favNumbers = []

def findNumbers(startRange, endRange):
    for i in b:
        if i%5==0 and i%7==0:
            favNumbers.append(i)

print(favNumbers)
```

Comment: sorry sir this doesn't work as well ...haha I tried running it but it only returned an empty list when I use starting number as 50 and 150 ,the results should be [70,105,140]